# Web Scraping All works as should but I have a error at the bottom of terminal

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I created my first web scraping program. Everything is working as desired, but there is an error at the bottom of the terminal I would like to understand the issue it is displaying and how I can get rid of it so it does not display in the future.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics+cards'
# opening the connection, grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs each products
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"item-container"})

filename = "products.csv"
# the "w" means write and
# "f" is the normal convention for a file writer
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, price, shipping\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]
    
    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    sales_main_container = container.findAll("ul", {"class":"price"})
    sales_container = sales_main_container[0]
    part_one_price = sales_container.find("strong").text
    part_two_price = sales_container.find("sup").text
    price = part_one_price + part_two_price

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class":"price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("price: " + price)
    print("shipping: " + shipping)

    f.write(brand + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + price.replace(",", "|") + "," + shipping + "\n")
    
f.close()
```

[Error displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTmT1.png)

[picture of it working as desired in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqLoU.png)

[excel file it creates successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2nS5.png)

But just in case clicking the link is an issue:

Here's the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/12082/Documents/Python/web_scrape/web_scraping.py", line 33, in 
part_one_price = sales_container.find("strong").text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Here's the how it displays in my terminal, which is how I intended:

brand: GIGABYTE
product_name: GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 2070 Super GAMING OC 3X 8G Graphics Card, GV-N207SGAMING OC-8GD
price: 549.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: EVGA
product_name: EVGA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti XC GAMING, 06G-P4-1263-KR, 6GB GDDR6, HDB Fan
price: 289.99
shipping: $3.99 Shipping
brand: GIGABYTE
product_name: GIGABYTE GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER DirectX 12 GV-N166SOC-6GD Video Card
price: 239.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: MSI
product_name: MSI GeForce RTX 2060 DirectX 12 RTX 2060 VENTUS XS 6G OC Video Card
price: 339.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: ASUS
product_name: ASUS ROG Strix Radeon RX 5700 XT ROG-STRIX-RX5700XT-O8G-GAMING Video Card
price: 459.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: EVGA
product_name: EVGA GeForce GTX 1660 SC ULTRA GAMING, 06G-P4-1067-KR, 6GB GDDR5, Dual Fan, Metal Backplate
price: 239.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: Sapphire Tech
product_name: SAPPHIRE PULSE Radeon RX 5700 XT 100416P8GL Video Card
price: 399.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: MSI
product_name: MSI GeForce GTX 1660 DirectX 12 GTX 1660 VENTUS XS 6G OC Video Card
price: 216.95
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: GIGABYTE
product_name: GIGABYTE Radeon RX 5700 XT DirectX 12 GV-R57XTGAMING-8GD Video Card
price: 409.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: XFX
product_name: XFX Radeon RX 5600 XT RX-56XT6DF46 Video Card THICC II PRO-14GBPS 6GB BOOST UP TO 1620M D6  3xDP HDMI
price: 299.99
shipping: Free Shipping
brand: ASRock
product_name: ASRock Radeon RX 5700 XT DirectX 12 RX 5700 XT TAICHI X 8G OC+ Video Card
price: 429.99
shipping: Free Shipping

Pasting it here doesnt display the same though, so I suggest clicking the link for this one if you need to see it.

And the excel file literally cant be pasted into text.

Comment: please post text instead of images for error messages and alike.

Comment: dude seriously, you downvote it because there are pictures?? the excel file pice doesnt convert to text in a way that would be beneficial.

Comment: use a debugger to locate the reason of the `None` value

Comment: I used it and it is saying the part_one_price and part_two_price have no attribute 'text'

Comment: I dont understand why it is working with this error and I dont know how I should change these variables. I literally have been following a video up until the price part of this script and dont know anything about python in this subject. I only know the basics atm

Comment: The part_one_price and part_two_price have no attribute 'text' means that beautifulsoup can't find any text in your sales container. It said it is a "NoneType" object means after some loop. Your sales container return nothing. This maybe because in your variable container have some Nonetype object when you do the first find_all.

Comment: Thank you all, I was able to solve a better way after your input.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is raising an exception when on line 33 (may also raise one on line 34 in some cases):

```py
    part_one_price = sales_container.find("strong").text
    part_two_price = sales_container.find("sup").text
```

Essentially what is happening is that there are instances of `sales_container` within your loop that do not have the expected `<strong>` and/or `<sup>` tags present. As a result of this `sales_container.find("strong")` will return `None`, this data type does not have an attribute `.text` so an exception is raised as in these cases you are basically saying `part_one_price = None.text` which is invalid.

To mitigate this risk, the below code (replacing lines 33-35 in your original post) could be used:

```py
    try: # Try to price from sales_container <strong> and <sup>
        part_one_price = sales_container.find("strong").text
        part_two_price = sales_container.find("sup").text
    except Exception as e: # If an exception is raised
        print(f"{product_name}: {e}") # Print the name of the product followed by the exception to the console
        part_one_price = "UNABLE TO PARSE PRICE" # Assign price not found message to var
        part_two_price = "" # Empty string to change part of price to clear from prev loop
    finally: # Once try or except has finished
        price = part_one_price + part_two_price # Concat both parts of price for later use
```

There are other areas in your code where exception handling may be valuable as to not stop the interpreter should a `None` value be accessed in an erroneous manner at runtime as in this case.